# How to access this json object

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using express js to send data from mysql. I send it using `res.json(theData)`.

In the client side I get it like this in the console:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "PlazaID":1,
         "PlazaName":"fff",
         "PlazaAddress":"fff",
         "PlazaContactNo":"45645",
         "PlazaLanes":"34",
         "PlazaStatus":"y",
         "ClientID":1
      },
      {
         "PlazaID":2,
         "PlazaName":"plaza2",
         "PlazaAddress":"p2",
         "PlazaContactNo":"000",
         "PlazaLanes":"2",
         "PlazaStatus":"a",
         "ClientID":2
      }
   ],
   "status":200,
   "config":{
      "method":"GET",
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "url":"/getTollPlaza",
      "headers":{
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
   },
   "statusText":"OK"
}
```

I store these values in an array to populate a table using angularjs' `ng-repeat` like this:

```
for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
    tableArray.push({
        plazaid:response.data[i].plazaid,
        plazaname:response.data[i].plazaname,
        plazaaddress:response.data[i].plazaaddress,
        plazacontactnumber:response.data[i].plazacontactnumber,
        plazalane:response.data[i].plazalane,
        plazastatus:response.data[i].plazastatus,
        clientid:response.data[i].clientid
    });
}
```

When I console.log the array the values are undefined.

```
0: Object
clientid:undefined
plazaaddress:undefined
plazacontactnumber:undefined
plazaid:undefined
plazalane:undefined
plazaname:undefined
plazastatus:undefined
```

Comment: its `ClientID` not `clientid`, javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: JSON keys are case sensitive

fix them and try again...

Comment: yeah your JSON keys are case sensitive you have call it with all the simple charectar   plazaid:response.data[i].plazaid   here it should be data[i].PlazaID like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Please note that variable name are case sensitive.

```
for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
    tableArray.push({
        plazaid:response.data[i].PlazaID,
        plazaname:response.data[i].PlazaName,
        plazaaddress:response.data[i].PlazaAddress,
        plazacontactnumber:response.data[i].PlazaContactNo,
        plazalane:response.data[i].PlazaLanes,
        plazastatus:response.data[i].PlazaStatus,
        clientid:response.data[i].ClientID
    });
}
```